# Ext JS 4 inline array store config

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

Is B) not the inline equivalent of A)?

```
// A) Create store with Ext.create
var storeInstance = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: ['company', 'price'],
    data: [
        ['3m Co',71.72],
        ['Alcoa Inc',29.01],
        ['Boeing Co.',75.43]
    ]
});

// B) Inline config object for store instanced in A)
var storeConfig = {
    xtype: 'store:array',  
    fields: [ 'company', 'price' ],
    data: [
        ['3m Co',71.72],
        ['Alcoa Inc',29.01],
        ['Boeing Co.',75.43]
    ]
};
```

Here's the code in a sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/cFD9W/1/

Answer (score 5):

In store inline config you need just specify type of store. 'xtype' works only for widgets (aliases with prefix 'widget')

```
var storeConfig = {
    type: 'array',
    fields: [ 'company', 'price' ],
    data: [
        ['3m Co',71.72],
        ['Alcoa Inc',29.01],
        ['Boeing Co.',75.43]
    ]
};
```

Try to print Ext.ClassManager.maps.aliasToName in console to understand aliases.